# I can't get multitem in json format AsyncStorage React native

Tags: typescript, react-native

i tryng to load all items saved in my asyncstorage, but my response does not return in json format, returns in this format:

```
 [["engineyard", "{\"login\":\"engineyard\",\"id\":81,\"node_id\":\"MDEyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjgx\",\"url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/engineyard\",\"repos_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/engineyard/repos\",\"events_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/engineyard/events\",\"hooks_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/engineyard/hooks\",\"issues_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/engineyard/issues\",\"members_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/engineyard/members{/member}\",\"public_members_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/engineyard/public_members{/member}\",\"avatar_url\":\"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/81?v=4\",\"description\":\"\"}"], ["errfree", "{\"login\":\"errfree\",\"id\":44,\"node_id\":\"MDEyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjQ0\",\"url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree\",\"repos_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/repos\",\"events_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/events\",\"hooks_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/hooks\",\"issues_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/issues\",\"members_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/members{/member}\",\"public_members_url\":\"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/public_members{/member}\",\"avatar_url\":\"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/44?v=4\",\"description\":null}"]]
```

but when i get only one item his return in json format, in this format i can't save in array to map

My code

```
const getOrgsSaved = async () => {
    let value = []
    try {
        const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        const Orgs = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
        return Orgs
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        return e;
    }
}
//my function where i get the items 
const  Main: React.FC = () => {
  const [orgsSave, setOrgsSaved] = useState<Array<Orgs>>([])
  const [orgsData, setOrgsData] = useState<Array<Orgs>>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    loadOrgs()
    getOrgsSaved()
  },[])
  const loadOrgs = () =>{
    Services.getOrgs()
      .then(response =>{
        setOrgsData(response.data)
      
      })
      .catch(e =>{
        console.log(e)
      })
  }
  function getOrgsSaved() {
    Services.getOrgsSaved() // here i get the response
      .then(response => {
        console.log('get',response)
        setOrgsSaved(response)
      })
 
     
  }
  return (
    <Box flex = {1} >
        <Navbar/>
        <SubHeader/>
        <OrgsList data = {orgsData}/>
        <Footer/>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

i tried to use JSON.parse but returns this error

> [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "engineyard"]

Answer (score 1):

It's because your first item is not in JSON format.
`engineyard` is parsed instead of `"engineyard"`.

When you have to store this string data, make sure also `JSON.encode` it before.
In your case, I guess you save the value as is, which is not good when it comes to parsing.

Comment: I tested the form i save, when i get one item the json returns ok
`{"login":"errfree","id":44,"node_id":"MDEyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjQ0","url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/events","hooks_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/hooks","issues_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/errfree/issues"} `